# Specify number of items in UITableView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have a basic table view which is showing data from multiple arrays.

My question is, the tableview needs to know how many cells it is going to show, thus the `numberOfRowsInSection` method which allows you to specify that.

In the `numberOfRowsInSection` method I am returning:

```
return [data_array count];
```

However, I have a feeling this is wrong. Because lets say the `data_array` has 100 items (0 to 99), then would doing `[data_array count]` return 100?

And if so, I am right in saying that I really need to do the following:

```
return ([data_array count] - 1);
```

By doing the above I am ensuring that I do not get an `outOfBounds` error.

Am I correct or I am begin stupid here?

Comment: That depends entirely on your implementation of your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: @CodeReaper Hardly.  If one wants one cell for each object in the array, then the answer is always the return from `count` and not to subtract anything from that.

Comment: If you return 100, the table will ask you for cells 0-99. Just like `count` returns the number of items in an array not the maximum safe index, `numberOfRowsInSection` needs to return the number of rows in the section, not the maximum safe index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the way you have it is correct. If you have an array [0-99], that is actually 100 items. You need 100 rows to display all that information.

The `numberOfRowsInSection` method needs the number of rows, not the 0 based index of the array.

The area where you actually access this data is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Here is where you get the 0 based indexPath that will let you know which index to use for data.

Example:
If your array was `@[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5"]`

You have 5 items, so you need 5 rows to display them.

`numberOfRowsInSection` should return `[array count]`, which is 5.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will give you 0 indexed values so you would do:

```
NSString *currentData = array[indexPath.row];
```

where `indexPath.row` will be values from 0-4, so no outOfBound errors

Answer (score 0):

The way you think is right, but to make more clear, `count` is position oriented (starts from 1) and on the other hand element in array is `index oriented` (starts from zero).

So, `numberOfRowsInSection` is expected to receive position oriented figure and `indexPath` deals with `index oriented` figure to access data for a row through array indicies.

So, it is correct to return `[data_array count]` instead of a one less value.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection%3a) which tells that the delegate function is expecting to get the number of elements which has nothing to do with the index of array.